# Label Text not updating from x:Static

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm writing a small internal app in XamarinForms and I'm trying to add localization using the fastest way as it's only two languages.

I have two Labels in the app :

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Data.Localization"

  <Label
          FontFamily="NubbuBold"
          HorizontalOptions="Center"
          Text="{x:Static local:LocalizationFile.main_ExpiryDatesForDayLabel}"
          TextColor="Crimson" />
<Label
          FontAttributes="Bold"
          FontFamily="NubbuBold"
          HorizontalOptions="Center"
          Text="{x:Static local:LocalizationFile.main_NewestExpiredDatesInStorage}" />
```

They're both referring to a Static class that holds static public properties for the text value.

```
 public static string main_ExpiryDatesForDayLabel { get; set; }
 public static string main_NewestExpiredDatesInStorage { get; set; }
```

When user changes app language, I call a method in the Static class that just changes the value of the string, for example :

```
main_ExpiryDatesForDayLabel = "Expiring Articles on Day :";
main_NewestExpiredDatesInStorage = "Newest Stales in Storage :";
```

The problem :
Application updates Label text only in the first label and no other control.
There is no difference in terms of way the values are changed or variables are defined.

The question :
Why only the first label? Everything is the same otherwise. I'm puzzled, but also not experienced enough in XF to know if this is some simple oversight. Is it possible to use this method to localize the app?

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK, `x:static` properties do not support dynamic changes. That is, the label won't update until "something else" causes page or label to redraw. If you change the static values BEFORE going to the page, it should work. Not enough info to know why the first one "works" but not the second one. If they are on the same page, then perhaps there is a xamarin bug such that the second static changing causes page redraw (thus fixing the first), but hasn't correctly updated the second at that time. If you add a third label, with a third static, do the first two get updated (but not the third)?

Comment: The first label is part of DataTemplate of CarouselView's  ItemTemplate. I believe this is the reason why it's getting updated. I got bamboozled into checking if it works and seeing that it does ... went on and wrote localization as such. Without realizing that it in fact can't, until the very end.

Comment: x:Static values will reflect the value that something has at the time of assignment and it will never change, if you want something to update at runtime it should be a `Binding` or a `DynamicResource`

Comment: FYI: *"The first label is part of DataTemplate of CarouselView's ItemTemplate."* For future questions, it is vital to show CONTEXT such as this, rather than just showing the line itself. As you have learned, *where* a XAML element appears matters. This affects when it is drawn/redrawn.

Comment: BTW, changing app language is rare. Statics work fine for this - you just need to get the app pages to redraw. After a language change, clear navigation stack, and go to app's first page. How to do so depends on whether you are using AppShell (Shell Navigation), or not.

Comment: Hey Steve, thanks. I  was awake way too long when I posted this, and I even checked if the label was child of something. But I was too tired... As for your comment, thanks. I'm using AppShell with TabBar and I'm looking into ways to redraw  pages within the tabbar right now. Please feel free to post your last comment as answer, as I belive it is very valuable and a true answer to my question. If you'd like, you can provide way to refresh AppShell TabBar pages as well, as it appears  that it's not commonly searched term for some reason.  Thanks!